# Flexbox causes side by side elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox in the following snippet.

However, the header and the div below it do not seem to get the CSS styling. If I remove the flexbox setting in the container div the header shows on top of the form div. But when I add display flex it puts the header and form div side by side.

Why does this happen? I am trying to show the header on top and form div below it and then horizontally center with justify-content: center. Thanks.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for helping us improve by taking this survey.</p>
  </header>
  <div id="form">
  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern=".+@.+\..+" required>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="number">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter your email" min="1" max="200" required>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What's your coding experience?</p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="noob" class="input-radio" />
        Noob
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="dangerous" class="input-radio" checked/>
        Dangerous
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="veteran" class="input-radio" />
        Veteran
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What programing language do you use the most at work?</p>
      <select id="dropdown" class="form-group" name="language" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select a language</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="c++">C++</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
        <option value="c#">C#</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p>Do you like to work on the Front-end or Back-end? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span</p>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="front-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Front-end
      </label>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="back-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Back-end
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Please provide any comments if we missed anything?</p>
      <textArea id="comments" name="comment" placeholder="Place your comments here..."></textArea>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <div>
  </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanna use the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) property. It takes four values:

- `row`
- `column`
- `row-reverse`
- `column-reverse`

You wanna edit container class to this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

For more information on Ordering Flex Items see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

---

**Edit**:

You can use the [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) property, which is a css-shorthand property for:

- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour for `display: flex` is to align items in a row. You can change this by adding `flex-flow: column` to align the items in a column.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column; /* added flex-flow: column here*/
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for helping us improve by taking this survey.</p>
  </header>
  <div id="form">
  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern=".+@.+\..+" required>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="number">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter your email" min="1" max="200" required>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What's your coding experience?</p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="noob" class="input-radio" />
        Noob
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="dangerous" class="input-radio" checked/>
        Dangerous
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="veteran" class="input-radio" />
        Veteran
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What programing language do you use the most at work?</p>
      <select id="dropdown" class="form-group" name="language" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select a language</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="c++">C++</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
        <option value="c#">C#</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p>Do you like to work on the Front-end or Back-end? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span</p>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="front-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Front-end
      </label>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="back-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Back-end
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Please provide any comments if we missed anything?</p>
      <textArea id="comments" name="comment" placeholder="Place your comments here..."></textArea>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <div>
  </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for helping us improve by taking this survey.</p>
  </header>
  <div id="form">
  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern=".+@.+\..+" required>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="number">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter your email" min="1" max="200" required>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What's your coding experience?</p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="noob" class="input-radio" />
        Noob
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="dangerous" class="input-radio" checked/>
        Dangerous
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="veteran" class="input-radio" />
        Veteran
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What programing language do you use the most at work?</p>
      <select id="dropdown" class="form-group" name="language" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select a language</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="c++">C++</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
        <option value="c#">C#</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p>Do you like to work on the Front-end or Back-end? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span</p>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="front-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Front-end
      </label>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="back-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Back-end
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Please provide any comments if we missed anything?</p>
      <textArea id="comments" name="comment" placeholder="Place your comments here..."></textArea>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <div>
  </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-flow:column` to **container**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

Add style below to header for align content inside the header to center.

```
header {
   align-items: center;
   justify-content:center;
   display:flex;
   flex-flow:column;
}
```

**Try this snippet**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content:center;
   display:flex;
   flex-flow:column;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for helping us improve by taking this survey.</p>
  </header>
  <div id="form">
  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern=".+@.+\..+" required>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="number">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter your email" min="1" max="200" required>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What's your coding experience?</p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="noob" class="input-radio" />
        Noob
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="dangerous" class="input-radio" checked/>
        Dangerous
      </label>
            <label>
        <input type="radio" name="user-experience" value="veteran" class="input-radio" />
        Veteran
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>What programing language do you use the most at work?</p>
      <select id="dropdown" class="form-group" name="language" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select a language</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="c++">C++</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
        <option value="c#">C#</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p>Do you like to work on the Front-end or Back-end? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span</p>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="front-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Front-end
      </label>
      <label>
        <input name="prefer" value="back-end-projects" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" />Back-end
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Please provide any comments if we missed anything?</p>
      <textArea id="comments" name="comment" placeholder="Place your comments here..."></textArea>
     <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <div>
  </form>
       </div>
</div>
```